# Getting ['Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: No matching activity!] error when using WebBrowser on android simulator in Expo Go

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am using an android simulator on Windows 10. I am using Expo Go to create an app and every time I try and use the WebBrowser within Expo Go I get this error. My simulator is running android 11. This works fine on iOS btw so I know it's something to do with android; possibly even the simulator.

Example to replicate the issue.

```
 WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("https://www.google.com"); //works fine on iOS - on android I get the error below:


[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: No matching activity!]
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:50 in promiseMethodWrapper
at node_modules\expo-modules-core\build\NativeModulesProxy.native.js:27:27 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
at http://192.168.0.21:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:158730:86 in openBrowserAsync$
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:190:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:212:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:239:8 in exports.async
at http://192.168.0.21:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:158699:37 in openBrowserAsync
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:190:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:212:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:239:8 in exports.async
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:697:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:634:6 in _receiveSignal
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:528:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:93:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackProd
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:318:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:342:2 in invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:439:41 in executeDispatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:463:19 in executeDispatchesInOrder
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2563:28 in executeDispatchesAndRelease
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1212:4 in forEachAccumulated
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2588:20 in runEventsInBatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2735:18 in runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2681:35 in batchedUpdates$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18204:13 in batchedUpdates$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2534:29 in batchedUpdates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2680:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2800:27 in receiveTouches
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this issue recently.

Try looking at the `Default Browser` setting under `Settings`=>`Apps`=>`Default Apps`=>`Browser App`

If it's set to `WebView Shell` switch it to `Chrome` or `Firefox` (or whichever browser you're using)

Comment: I gotcha. On the android simulator settings you mean?